# Print Window does not Capture in online game

Tags: c#, dllimport, user32

I'm trying to create a simple auto-access program.
Capture with that code only saves the gray picture.
What should I do?
Other programs that are not games are captured normally.
Is it because of the security program?
And I tried to type a keyboard into that game, but it doesn't work at all.

> - SendKeys.SendWait("W")
> - SendKeys.Send("W")
> - InputSimulator
> - SendInput

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    String AppPlayerName = "LOST ARK (64-bit) v.1.0.1.3";

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]

    static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);



    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    static extern int GetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn);



    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]

    static extern IntPtr CreateRectRgn(int nLeftRect, int nTopRect, int nRightRect, int nBottomRect);


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr findwindow = FindWindow(null, AppPlayerName);
        if (findwindow != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Found.");
            Debug.WriteLine(findwindow.ToString());
            PrintWindow(findwindow);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Not Found");
        }
    }

    public static void PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)

    {

        Rectangle rc = Rectangle.Empty;

        Graphics gfxWin = Graphics.FromHwnd(hwnd);

        rc = Rectangle.Round(gfxWin.VisibleClipBounds);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

        bool succeeded = PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 1);

        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);

        if (!succeeded)

        {

            gfxBmp.FillRectangle(

                new SolidBrush(Color.Gray),

                new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));

        }

        IntPtr hRgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);

        GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hRgn);

        Region region = Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);

        if (!region.IsEmpty(gfxBmp))

        {

            gfxBmp.ExcludeClip(region);

            gfxBmp.Clear(Color.Transparent);

        }

        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        bmp.Save(Application.StartupPath + "1.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The games are not use the GDI to display a content. 
Your program is create a GDI object (Graphic) and copy the content from it. But the games and 3d editors are used the DirectX, OpenGL or any other direct access to video. They bypass the GDI level.

In old time it was called theater mode.

Please use this article, when the game is uses directx:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ru-RU/c582109f-6b6f-4d5a-9b47-720145d21411/capture-screenshots-of-fullscreen-directx-games-in-c?forum=Offtopic